# Dart Error: error: import of dart:mirrors is not supported in the current Dart runtime

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-platform, gcloud, google-cloud-pubsub

I'm currently trying to make some mobile code with Flutter. I'm trying to publish/subscribe data to GCP Cloud Pub/Sub using gcloud library dart. Here is the code for the main.dart:

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:googleapis_auth/auth_io.dart' as auth;
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:gcloud/db.dart';
import 'package:gcloud/storage.dart';


import 'package:gcloud/pubsub.dart';
import 'package:gcloud/service_scope.dart' as ss;
import 'package:gcloud/src/datastore_impl.dart' as datastore_impl;

Future<int> main() async {

  // Read the service account credentials from the file.
var jsonCredentials = new File('path/file.json').readAsStringSync();
var credentials = new auth.ServiceAccountCredentials.fromJson(jsonCredentials);

// Get an HTTP authenticated client using the service account credentials.
var scopes = []    
    ..addAll(PubSub.SCOPES);
var client = await auth.clientViaServiceAccount(credentials, scopes);


// Instantiate objects to access Cloud Datastore, Cloud Storage
// and Cloud Pub/Sub APIs.
var pubsub = new PubSub(client, 'project-name');
ss.fork(() {
  // register the services in the new service scope.
  registerPubSubService(pubsub);

  // Run application using these services.
});

var topic = await pubsub.createTopic('flutter');
await topic.publishString('coba publish dr flutter');

var subscription =
    await pubsub.createSubscription('sub_flutter', 'flutter');
var pullEvent = await subscription.pull();
print(pullEvent.message.asString);
await pullEvent.acknowledge();

  return 0;
}
```

Here are the denpendencies on the pubspec.yaml:

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  googleapis: ^0.54.0
  googleapis_beta: ^0.49.0
  googleapis_auth: ^0.2.10
  gcloud: ^0.6.3
```

When trying to debug the code I get the following errors:

```
Launching lib\main.dart on vivo 1918 in debug mode...
Built build\app\outputs\apk\debug\app-debug.apk.
E/flutter (20586): [ERROR:flutter/shell/common/shell.cc(178)] Dart Error: error: import of dart:mirrors is not supported in the current Dart runtime
E/flutter (20586): [ERROR:flutter/shell/common/engine.cc(188)] Could not prepare to run the isolate.
E/flutter (20586): [ERROR:flutter/shell/common/engine.cc(127)] Engine not prepare and launch isolate.
E/flutter (20586): [ERROR:flutter/shell/common/shell.cc(407)] Could not launch engine with configuration.
```

Comment: dart mirrors aren't supported in Flutter

Comment: do you have any suggestion how can i publish/subscribe from cloud pubsub in flutter ?

Answer (score 40):

In my case, for one of the projects, I had both 'package:json_annotation/json_annotation.dart' and 'package:json_serializable/json_serializable.dart' imported in the dart file. Removing json_serializable package resolved the above error.

Comment: That's a life saver !!! I spent almost 2 hours not knowing the reason

Comment: In my case it was 'package:json_serializable/builder.dart'. Thanks!

Comment: @NBM is a true life saver

Comment: You really save my life ! Thx

Answer (score 5):

Global search `json_serializable .dart` (ctrl+shift+f) in your project. If you find any import `import 'package:json_serializable/json_serializable.dart'`  which is not used or unnecessarily imported, remove the import and re-run the project.
Hope this may help!

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately the glcoud package for dart is not compatible with flutter (or web) due to the mirror package.

I suggest you to open an issue on the github repository about supporting gcloud pub/sub on flutter.
https://github.com/dart-lang/gcloud/issues/new

I can also check the [googleapis](https://pub.dev/packages/googleapis) package which has a pub/sub implementation that might fit your needs.
https://pub.dev/documentation/googleapis/latest/googleapis.pubsub.v1/googleapis.pubsub.v1-library.html. (use by glcoud package)

Comment: I raised an issue for the same: https://github.com/dart-lang/gcloud/issues/84

Answer (score 1):

This way fixed my error:

```
dev_dependencies:
 build_runner: ^1.0.0
 json_serializable: ^3.2.0

 flutter_test:
  sdk: flutter
```

Actually I put `json_serializable` dependency on top of flutter dev_dependencies and it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

For me, I was working on creating my own code generator and I was getting this error every time I tried to run tests on it.

I was trying to run them with `flutter test`, but I needed to instead use `flutter pub run build_runner test`.

Side note, make sure to replace all:

`import 'package:flutter_test/flutter_test.dart;`

with:

`import 'package:test/test.dart';`

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs when a package uses `dart:mirrors` in your flutter project.

If you have any imports for example from `utils.dart` that includes dart:mirrors this error happens.

> Dart includes dart:mirrors, which provides type reflection. But since Flutter apps are pre-compiled for production, and binary size is always a concern with mobile apps, this library is unavailable for Flutter apps.
> (https://docs.flutter.dev/resources/faq#does-flutter-come-with-a-reflection--mirrors-system)

When I had to face this issue, the reason why i had this error, was the import of the following package: `package:auto_route_generator/utils.dart`

Comment: In my case reason is the same. but I need to use package:auto_route_generator/utils.dart import. What is the solution you implemented?

Answer (score 0):

I was creating my own code generation tool and got the next error while running a test: `Dart Error: error: import of dart:mirrors is not supported in the current Dart runtime`

In my case the error was because Flutter doesn't allow to use Dart's mirrors (for the "tree shaking") and  forgot to remove `flutter` dependency in the `pubspec.yaml`:

```yaml
dependencies:
  flutter: # <-----------  remove this line
    sdk: flutter # <----------- remove this line

  meta: ^1.7.0
  analyzer: ^4.7.0
  build: ^2.3.1
  source_gen: ^1.2.5
```

Answer (score 0):

I added new package "class_to_map".
Then I get "Error: error: import of dart:mirrors is not supported in the current Dart runtime".
You need remove last package.