# Implementing MQTT using Google cloud pub sub in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-platform, mqtt, iot

Is there any way to establish a connection with Google IoT pub-sub API in flutter?

I tried this [library](https://github.com/shamblett/mqtt_client) but it doesn't have the configuration which I am looking for.

I have the following data which will be used to establish the connection:

```
{
  "type": ,
  "project_id": ,
  "private_key_id": ,
  "private_key": "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\n...\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n",
  "client_email": ,
  "client_id": ,
  "auth_uri": ,
  "token_uri": ,
  "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": ,
  "client_x509_cert_url": 
}
```

Comment: Have you tried connecting?

Comment: I don't recommend you to use third-party libraries to connect with Google services. Use libraries that are being provided by Google. Client libraries for Google PubSub are listed here at https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/reference/libraries

Comment: What's wrong with `mqtt_client` ?

Comment: @DinkoPehar please check the following links: 
https://github.com/shamblett/mqtt_client/issues/136 and https://github.com/shamblett/iot-home/issues/4

Answer (score 3):

You can use [gcloud](https://pub.dev/packages/gcloud) package in your flutter app. It provides support for Cloud Datastore, Cloud Storage, and Cloud Pub/Sub. Hope it helps.

P.S. Don't use any third-party libraries to connect with Google services. It may not have full support or may stop working at any point of time. Use libraries that are being provided by Google. Other client libraries for Google PubSub are listed [here](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/reference/libraries).

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I tried to implement gcloud package in my flutter app but it is not compatible with flutter.
please check the following link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58472589/dart-error-error-import-of-dartmirrors-is-not-supported-in-the-current-dart-r