# E/flutter (24350): [ERROR:flutter/shell/common/shell.cc(93)] Dart Error: error: import of dart:mirrors is not supported in the current Dart runtime

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart

I worked yesterday on my project when suddenly the following error appeared after I imported a dependencie (**flutter_typeahead: ^4.0.0**).

```
E/flutter (25254): [ERROR:flutter/shell/common/shell.cc(93)] Dart Error: error: import of dart:mirrors is not supported in the current Dart runtime
E/flutter (25254): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_isolate.cc(143)] Could not prepare isolate.
E/flutter (25254): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/runtime_controller.cc(382)] Could not create root isolate.
E/flutter (25254): [ERROR:flutter/shell/common/shell.cc(600)] Could not launch engine with configuration
```

But I don't think that was caused by this dependencie because when i removed it and commented all the code I wrote the past 2 hours, the error still persists.

Here is what i tried to do:

- Run `flutter clean`
- Remove all the files in `{Flutter SDK path}\flutter\bin\cache`
- Remove the `.pub-cache` file in `{Flutter SDK path}\flutter\`
- And lastly run `flutter run`

I really don't know what can cause this error because after I did that all, I had literally the same code and the same dependencies than when the code was still compiling.

Everywhere i am looking for this error, people talk about `json_serializable` and `json_annotation.` but i don't use thoses packages ([Dart Error: error: import of dart:mirrors is not supported in the current Dart runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58472589/dart-error-error-import-of-dartmirrors-is-not-supported-in-the-current-dart-r/73322159#73322159)).

Finally I tried to run a older version of my code when the same packages (also **flutter_typeahead: ^4.0.0**) and it worked. Now I will try to integrate the new code into my old version to see if this error occurs again. That will cost me serveral hours of work but I think I don't have any choice because i can't find the issue.

If someone has any solution to this problem, I would be really curious about, where it can come from, what can cause it and what is the solution to this error.

Here are the dependencies I am using even i don't think that this error is linked with theme:

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  flutter_bloc: ^8.0.1
  get_it: ^7.2.0
  firebase_auth: ^3.3.19
  firebase_core: ^1.17.1
  cloud_firestore: ^3.1.17
  dartz: ^0.10.1
  auto_route: ^4.0.1
  auto_route_generator: ^4.0.0
  build_runner: ^2.1.11
  uuid: ^3.0.6
  badges: ^2.0.3
  qr_code_scanner: ^1.0.0
  cloud_functions: ^3.3.2
  firebase_app_check: ^0.0.6+18
  smooth_page_indicator: ^1.0.0+2
  charts_flutter: ^0.12.0
  connectivity_plus: ^2.2.1
  intl: ^0.17.0
  http: ^0.13.4
  flutter_typeahead: ^4.0.0
 
dev_dependencies:
  
flutter_launcher_icons: "^0.10.0"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found a solution to my Problem. Here was the issue:

The import of  `import 'package:auto_route_generator/utils.dart'`

6 hours debbuging for a simple import. I wanna die.

I also found the reason why that happens. This error occurs when a package uses `dart:mirrors` in your flutter project. If there are any imports for example from `utils.dart` that includes `dart:mirrors` this error happens.

> Dart includes dart:mirrors, which provides type reflection. But since
> Flutter apps are pre-compiled for production, and binary size is
> always a concern with mobile apps, this library is unavailable for
> Flutter apps.
> (https://docs.flutter.dev/resources/faq#does-flutter-come-with-a-reflection--mirrors-system)